# sed -n function calling in same line repeatedly

Tags: sed

I'm a complete novice wrt unix and writing shell scripts, so apologies if the solution to my problem is quite banal.

Essentially though, I'm working on a shell script that reads from a TextEdit file called "sursecout.txt", and runs it through another script called "sursec.x" (where sursec.x is simply a series of FORTRAN integrations). It then creates a folder named after a certain Jacobi integral ("CJ ="), and stores the ten SurSec[n] files there (where n = integer). My problem is that the different folders are created correctly with appropriate names, but are each filled with identical output files. My suspicion is that something is wrong with my sed command, in that it's reading the same two lines over and over again (where as it should be reading the first two lines of sursecout.txt, then next two, etc.)

Here are the first two folders I want to make, but I have 30 so any help would be appreciated.

```
./sursec.x < ./sursecout.txt
sed -n '1,2p;3q' sursecout.txt
cd ..
mv ./data ./CJ=3.029990
mkdir data
cd SurSec
```

```
./sursec.x < ./sursecout.txt
sed -n '3,4p;5q' sursecout.txt
cd ..
mv ./data ./CJ=3.030659
mkdir data
cd SurSec
```

Comment: sed does not edit in place unless the `-i` option is used, otherwise it sends its result to stdout. But perhaps you want to split your file into separate files with 2 consecutive lines each (see `split -l2 file`).

Comment: I have 30 folders I want to make, so it becomes quite tedious to do it like that. But do you simply mean replacing ```-n``` with ```-i```?

Comment: Break the problem down into smaller parts. What does surscecout.txt contain?. What does sursec.x produce? Where does the name `CJ=3.020990` come from and can it be calculated with a function or read from a list? At the moment all I see from the sed command it produces 2 lines from sursecout.txt and these will be displayed on the monitor or in a log file.